# Why does Angular 2 name a module NgModule and not just Module

Tags: angular, module, naming, consistency

So in Angular 2, a lot of things improved compared to Angular1 (AngularJS). I'm really happy with it. But what confuses me the most is the in my opinion inconsistent naming:

Component: `@Component`
Module: `@NgModule`

Why would the module be prefixed with Ng, when the component is not? Is there any reason for this inconsistent naming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Module` is quite overloaded (ES6 modules) for example. 
There is a lot of confusion about TypeScript imports and `@NgModule({imports: [...]})` for example.

They just wanted to make it clear what this module concept is about.
`Component` is much more unlikely to be confused when Angular is used.

Comment: But shouldn't they use NgComponent just for the sake of consistency then?

Comment: There would be a lot of things where they could add `ng` or `Ng` as prefix. Also `NgModule` was introduced just days before Angular 2.0.0 final was released. A lot of Angular code existed at this time already because people started working with Angular with alpha versions already. Consistency is not that important.

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, JavaScript has a concept of modules. TypeScript shares this concept.

[Modules (TypeScript)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Modules are an already existing concept in TypeScript and ECMAScript. They probably didn't want to introduce a double meaning for "Module".